# Need help debugging my code

Tags: android, debugging, audio

I need some input about my code.
Basically, I have a method to load music from Class A

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
    musicIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    filePath = cursor.getString(musicIndex);
    fileName = new File(filePath).getName();
    playMusic();//Play the selected music
}

public void playMusic(){
    if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mPlayer.reset();
    }
    try{
        mPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
        BeatDetection beatDetect = new BeatDetection();
        beatDetect.init();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

That method will call the `init()` method in Class B

```
public void init() throws Exception{
    energy = 0;
    variance = 0;
    constant = 0;
    isBeat = false;
    sensitivity = 0;
    dBuffer = new float[sampleRate / bufferSize];
    eBuffer = new float[sampleRate / bufferSize];
    timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    MusicLoad msc = new MusicLoad();

    totalMs = 0;
    seeking = true;
    //msc.printText();
    decode(msc.fileName, 25, 40);
}
```

In that method, it initializes everything and call the `decode()` method

```
public void decode(String path, int startMs, int maxMs)
  throws IOException, javazoom.jl.decoder.DecoderException {

    debug();
    File in = new File(path);
    InputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(in), 8 * 1024);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    try {
         Bitstream bitstream = new Bitstream(inStream);
        Decoder decoder = new Decoder();

        boolean done = false;
        while (! done) {
            Header frameHeader = bitstream.readFrame();
            if (frameHeader == null) {
                done = true;
            } else {
                totalMs += frameHeader.ms_per_frame();

                if (totalMs >= startMs) {
                    seeking = false;
                }

                if (! seeking) {
                    SampleBuffer output = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream);

                    if (output.getSampleFrequency() != 44100 || output.getChannelCount() != 2) {
                        throw new javazoom.jl.decoder.DecoderException("mono or non-44100 MP3 not supported", null);
                    }

                    short[] pcm = output.getBuffer();
                    for (short s : pcm) {
                        outStream.write(s & 0xff);
                        outStream.write((s >> 8 ) & 0xff);
                    }
                }

                if (totalMs >= (startMs + maxMs)) {
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            bitstream.closeFrame();
        }

        byte[] abAudioData = outStream.toByteArray();
        calculation(abAudioData);
    } catch (BitstreamException e) {
        throw new IOException("Bitstream error: " + e);
    } catch (DecoderException e) {
        Log.w("Decoder error", e);
        throw new javazoom.jl.decoder.DecoderException("Error",e);
    } finally {
        inStream.close();
    }
}
```

Don't mind reading all the code lines. If you guys notice I put `debug()` in the beginning to see whether the method is called or not. At this point, the `debug()` is properly called. However, if I put the `debug()` after the line `File in = new File(path);`, the `debug()` will not be called anymore. It seems like the code is stop running at that point.

The ultimate result is, I can load and play the song without any problem. However, the `decode()` is not called and there is no error whatsoever. I'm stuck at pointing out the problem at this point. So if there's any input please help me.

EDIT: After I tried tracing the "path" variable, it returns NULL so the error is NullPointerException. Seems like the "fileName" variable from Class A is not passed to Class B. Any suggestion?

Comment: Where is the definition of File?

Comment: See if any exception is thrown in `playMusic()`, put `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block

Comment: Figured out the problem, I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse with ADT then it's very easy to debug your Android apps, just add a breakpoint (probably in the new File(...) line) and see what happens.

My guess here is that `File in = new File(path);` probably is throwing a IOException in your `decode` method, that exception is bubbling first to `init()` and then to `playMusic()`, where it is caught by try catch block. Your catch is empty so you are not seeing anything. Try debugging as I said or add some logging info in the catch block.

Comment: Use the debugging tools I've mentioned. Trace the path variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is just something to look at, but from the doc page

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29

> "The actual file referenced by a File may or may not exist. It may also, despite the name File, be a directory or other non-regular file."

If you had the path wrong, it may be trying to create the file and you may not have the correct permission to do so. Perhaps: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I just wanted to show how to get the file path to read/write files for others that come across this post as I have:

```
String filePath = myContext.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/sysout.log";
File file  = new File(filePath);
```

These two lines will create (open if it exists, and overwrite) a file named "sysout.log" in the folder `/data/data/com.app.name/files/`; myContext is just the current context. Using this technique alleviates problems with defining your own path name. Hope this helps someone.